# Selecting "one" of many anchor tags from a paragraph on mouuseup?

Tags: jquery

i am in trouble with this code

```
$(document).on('mouseup','.editor p',function(e){
             var id = $(this).attr('name');

             var $text = window.getSelection(this);
             var al =$(this).find('a').length;
             if($(this).text($text).w)
});
```

how can i select one anchor tag on `mouseup` selection based from the text below:

```
<div class="editor">
<p name="909037734">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of 
using <a id="14998538924729" title="Click to follow link" class="pinkLink" target="_blank" href="http://google.com">Lorem Ipsum</a> is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of 
letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it 
look like readable English. Many desktop publishing <a id="93420055379223" title="Click to follow link" class="pinkLink" target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com">packages</a> and web 
page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a 
search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their 
infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by 
accident, sometimes on purpose (injected <a id="52337704157880" title="Click to follow link" class="pinkLink" target="_blank" href="http://yahoo.com">humour</a> and the like).</p></div>
```

please tell me about this.

Comment: on mouseup what you need?suppose if i click the anchor button what you need exactly?

Comment: on mouseup i have code var $text = window.getSelection(this); this gives me the mouseup selected text. now i want to check that text is already in an anchor tag ?

Comment: I think you talking about the if you select text you need to remove anchor tag from this text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).on('mouseup','.editor p',function(e){
    if(e.target.text!=undefined){
        $("#"+e.target.id).before($("#"+e.target.id).html());
        $("#"+e.target.id).remove();
    }
});
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/JNVV2/1/)

Hope it will help

Comment: Hey sonusindhu this code works according to my requirement 
thanks a millions for rapidly answer my question

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following JS fiddle

hope this is what you want

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/z97br/1/

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.editor p',function(e)
    {
    if(e.target.text!=undefined)
    {
            alert(e.target.text);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes arun i think m near to solution .plz tell me this code checks only anchor tag with selected text

Comment: arun but i do not want to work with click function here only need to check text on mouse up. can you please edit the code on jsfiddle according to my requirements

Comment: The mouseup event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer is over the element, and the mouse button is released...means clciked...so what u want may be  on hover event?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
var al = $(this).find('a');
al[1].click();//OR what erver you prefer
```